# Query to aggregate on 2 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks as below

My data table looks like this:

```
client_id   Status      room
   1         a           XS
   1         b           XS
   1         d           XS
   1         e           L
   2         a           M
   2         d           M
   3         a           XS
   3         b           XS
   3         e           L
   4         a           L
   4         d           L
   5         b           XS
```

I need to group by client where status has values both a and d
and also group by client where client has ever been in the room XS.

The result set from above should return

```
client_id     a_d_Flag       Xs_flag
   1             Yes           Yes
   2             Yes           No
   3             No            Yes
   4             Yes           No
   5             No            Yes
```

Query :

```
select client_id, 
       case when count(distinct case when Status in ('a', 'd') then Status end) = 2
           then 'Yes'
           else 'No'
         end as a_d_Flag 
     case when room = 'XS'
     then 'Yes'
     else 'No'
   end as xs_flag
from   client_details
group by client_id,room
```

Comment: *Presumably* your query isn't working? Shouldn't you just be grouping by `client_id` and you aggregates should be around the `CASE` expression? Look up "pivoting" or "conditional aggregation".

Comment: You can literally copy the answer to your last question and add a second case expression to handle this.

Comment: Please don't expect us to do all your work for you, learn from your past answers

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the conditional aggregation :

```
select client_id, 
      case when count(distinct case when Status in ('a', 'd') then Status end) = 2
      then 'Yes' else 'No' end a_d_flag,
      case when max(case when room = 'XS' then 1 end) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Xs_flag
from client_details
group by client_id
```

Result :

| client_id | a_d_flag | Xs_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | Yes | No |
| 3 | No | Yes |
| 4 | Yes | No |
| 5 | No | Yes |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VcPHbMDt)